# Find the mistakes(pumping lemma proof). Can you help me?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, pumping-lemma

There are pumping lemma proof. I have to find one mistake. Please help me [lemma proof][1]

Comment: For future questions, try copying the whole question and not posting a link with a photo, as it helps people see at a glance if they can help you. If they have to put extra effort to help you, you will get less help (and the way this is asked lets people see that this is probably your homework, and answering homework is generally frowned upon)

Answer (score 2):

The fact $\ell > 0$ does not imply that $a^{n+\ell}a^n$ is not in the language. For example, for $n=2,\ell=2$ you have that it is a sequence of $6$ times the $a$ character, which belongs to the language, as it equals $a^3a^3$. The last part of the argument is then flawed.